# Confused getting the value in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a node js code to do the below.

1. Read a file line by line
2. Find a regex match and assign to a variable
3. use this value in the following match.

Here is the code that I'm using.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const readFile = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('./readFile.txt'),
    output: fs.createWriteStream('./writeTxt.txt'),
    terminal: false
});

readFile
    .on('line', transform)
    .on('close', function () {
        console.log(`Created "${this.output.path}"`);
    });

function transform(line) {
    var stringToReplace;
    var string = line;
    var re = new RegExp("^<lsec uid='(.*)' d='(.*)' n='' anchor='(.*)'>$");
    var re1 = new RegExp("^<lsbsec d='(.*)' sbsecloc='(.*)' sbsecanchor='(.*)'>$");
    if (re.test(string)) {
        stringToReplace = string.replace(/<lsec uid='(.*)' d='(.*)' n='' anchor='(.*)>/g, "$1")
        console.log(stringToReplace);
    } else if (re1.test(string)) {
        console.log(stringToReplace)
    }
    else {
        console.log("Invalid");
    }

}
```

and the output that I get is

```
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
undefined
Invalid
Invalid
2
Invalid
Invalid
undefined
Invalid
Invalid
3
Invalid
Invalid
undefined
Invalid
Invalid
```

But the output that I'm expecting is instead of `undefined`, the `Number` should be there.

Here is my text file.

```
<lsec uid='1' d='1' n='' anchor='1'> = > 1
<name>Normal Text</name> 
<p>Normal Text
<lsbsec d='1' sbsecloc='(1)' sbsecanchor='(1)'>
<p>Normat Text</lsbsec>
</lsec>
<lsec uid='2' d='2' n='' anchor='2'>
<name>Normal Text</name>
<p>Normal Text
<lsbsec d='1' sbsecloc='(1)' sbsecanchor='(1)'>
<p>Normat Text</lsbsec>
</lsec>
<lsec uid='3' d='2' n='' anchor='2'>
<name>Normal Text</name>
<p>Normal Text
<lsbsec d='1' sbsecloc='(1)' sbsecanchor='(1)'>
<p>Normat Text</lsbsec>
</lsec>
```

This is very confusing.

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Using regex to operate on XML isn't such a good idea.

Comment: You are missing `stringToReplace = string.replace(/<lsbsec d='(.*)' sbsecloc='(.*)' sbsecanchor='(.*)'>/g, "$1")` this in `else if` condition. which results in undefined. replacing this will results in numbered output you are expecting instead of `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting a value for stringToReplace in the else if.

Comment: Then how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Undefined value is undefined

```
else if (re1.test(string)) {
        console.log(stringToReplace)
    }
```

here `stringToReplace` is undefined as no value is assigned to it previously.

May be you wanted to:

```
else if (re1.test(string)) {
        //same expression as in if
        stringToReplace = string.replace(/<lsec uid='(.*)' d='(.*)' n='' anchor='(.*)>/g, "$1")
        console.log(stringToReplace)
    }
```

EDIT(comment based):

```
if (re.test(string) || re1.test(string)) {
        stringToReplace = string.replace(/<lsec uid='(.*)' d='(.*)' n='' anchor='(.*)>/g, "$1")
        console.log(stringToReplace);
}
```

Comment: 1 quick question, might be dumb.. Here I'm already assigning the value in block 1 `if`, I want to use the same value in `else if`

Comment: Then take the stringtoreplace assignment expression, outside else if , or just include the same expression in both else if clause.

Comment: I'm so sorry, didn't get you...I'm trying to print the value that I got in if block in else if block...

Comment: @user3872094, For each line `stringToReplace` will be re-initialized so u won't be able to use it in case of `else if`